# Print error in Word 2013

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a print macro that sends the first page to our letterhead printer and all remaining pages to a plain paper printer.  The document is then printed a second time on plain paper for our records.  While the macro worked when I was using XP and Word 2010, after a recent upgrade to Windows 7 and Office 2013, the macro sometimes crashes the entire Word application.  That is, if I run the macro, Word crashes.  If I step through the macro, it works just fine.  This macro is used multiple time a day and I would hate to lose it due to my recent upgrade.

Any ideas to save the macro?

Macro code below to which which I assign the keyboard shortcut of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Thank you

```
Public Sub LetterheadPrint()
    ' sends page 1 to the letterhead printer (\\scprint04\ASHPLJ5)
    ' sends page 2 to the regular printer (\\scprint04\ASTaxBill)
    ' prints another copy on plain paper

    On Cancel GoTo Cancelled:
    On Error GoTo Cancelled:

    ' save current printer
    Dim sCurrentPrinter As String
    sCurrentPrinter = Application.ActivePrinter

    ' Print Assessee Copy
    ' page 1 to letterhead printer
    Application.ActivePrinter = "\\scprint04\ASHPLJ5"
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut Range:=wdPrintFromTo, From:="1", To:="1"

    ' remaining pages to regular printer
    Application.ActivePrinter = "\\scprint04\ASTaxBill"
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut Range:=wdPrintFromTo, From:="2"

    ' Print Office Copy
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut

Cancelled:

    'Restore original printer
    Application.ActivePrinter = sCurrentPrinter

On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Wild guess....try to change the shortcut key...Ctrl-Shift-P is for font size and may be causing an issue.

Comment: Sometimes all we have is a wild guess.  At least you had one when I did not.  I removed the keyboard shortcut and ran the macro using the "Run" button in the macro window.  It still crashed the entire application.  Thanks for the guess.

Answer (score 0):

> Ctrl+Shift+P is for Font Size Select, that could be the problem

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub LetterheadPrint()
    ' sends page 1 to the letterhead printer (\\scprint04\ASHPLJ5)
    ' sends page 2 to the regular printer (\\scprint04\ASTaxBill)
    ' prints another copy on plain paper

    Dim cancel As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    On cancel GoTo Cancelled:
    'On Error GoTo Cancelled:


    ' save current printer
    Dim sCurrentPrinter As String
    sCurrentPrinter = Application.ActivePrinter

    ' Print Assessee Copy
    ' page 1 to letterhead printer
    Application.ActivePrinter = "ASHPLJ5"
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut Range:=wdPrintFromTo, From:="1", To:="1"

    ' remaining pages to regular printer
    Application.ActivePrinter = "ASTaxBill"
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut Range:=wdPrintFromTo, From:="2"

    ' Print Office Copy
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut

Cancelled:

    'Restore original printer
    Application.ActivePrinter = sCurrentPrinter
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

[Global.ActivePrinter Property (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838478.aspx)

> Documents created in an earlier version, such as Word 2010, will always open in compatibility mode in Word 2013, so open it and save it as new version

I would also suggest you installing the latest version driver and Office Updates

Comment: Another good guess but alas, no joy.  I have saved the original doc in the latest version.  I even tried creating a doc from scratch to remove any chance of incompatibility.  Still did not work.

Comment: @TCottengim i am running win7 office10 the seems to work with no errors. try removing `On Error GoTo Cancelled:` and then run the macro see what errors your getting.

Comment: I tired deleting the error trap but it still crashes when run normally.  Stepping through still works.  I think you may have hit on the problem though.  I am running Win 7 and Office 2013 so I think Office may be the problem here.  FYI: XP and Office 2010 also works normally.

Comment: @TCottengim if your using local server printer try change `Application.ActivePrinter = "\\scprint04\ASTaxBill"` to `Application.ActivePrinter = "ASTaxBill"`

Comment: Although it is a network resource, I tried anyway.  Again no joy.  What bothers me about this is that if I step through in debug mode, it works fine.  It only crashes when run "normally".